# copying specific data from one table to another in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a created a table employee in MySQL which consists of a columns
**emp_id,emp_name,emp_salary,work_hours**

i have another table **employee_dup which consists of same number of columns,with same datatypes and names as well**

i want to copy all the data present in employee into employee_dup, even though i want all the records to be copied, with respect to work_hours i am particular ,i want only the integer data greater than 10 to be inserted into work_hours column of salary_dup

so basically everything from salary has to be copied into salary_dup except the values that are less than 10 that are present in work_hours column

i tried writing the query

```
insert into salary_dup (empname,empsal,hours)select empame,empsal,hours>10 from salary;
```

did'nt work

the check constraint has not been added to hours column in salary_dup table
is there anyway to achieve this through a query without check constraint ,please help me

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use a `where` clause:

```
insert into salary_dup (empname, empsal, hours)
    select empame, empsal, hours
    from salary
    where hours > 10;
```

Note:  This filters out rows where hours are <= 10, which is how I interpret the question.

If you actually wanted *all rows* but to hide hours that are less than 10, then use a `case` expression:

```
insert into salary_dup (empname, empsal, hours)
    select empame, empsal, (case when hours > 10 then hours end)
    from salary;
```

Comment: thank you the second query that you wrote was the solution i needed